# Best way to create in app notifcation based on value from a Json field

Tags: java, json, notifications, android-notifications, in-app

I have some data in my Json.
This data updates automatically every 20 seconds.

There is a field in that josn called power
Values of power could be from int 1 to 600

I would like to create a class which would check the value of power every 20 seconds and alert the user using in app notification if the value of the power goes above or below a certain value.

What is the best way of achieving this ? Is there a library that can be used ?

Answer (score 0):

There are many patterns you can use.

You can opt for using a library such a quartz: http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/

or you can create a chron job on your OS that would do what quartz does: http://kvz.io/blog/2007/07/29/schedule-tasks-on-linux-using-crontab/ (I'd go with quartz)

Or you can do it yourself:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html